# Do the webhook callback urls have to be https?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'am currently trying to get messages from circuit working in my kotlin environment.
Registering a webhook works fine but circuit is not triggering my local webserver.
Does it have to be ssl/tls and if yes does the sandbox accept self signed ceritificates?

My Webserver seems to work if I call it myself local or over internet.
Does it have to be a certain port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be http or https and if it is https, self signed certificates are accepted. 
It has to be the default port for http (80) and https (443), you can not specify 8080 or 3000 or any other "local ports". 
If you have a problem with that, I would recommend working with ngrok